# How to print dict in separate line?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import re
sums = dict()
fh= open('wordcount.txt','r')
for line in fh:
    words = [word.lower() for word in re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', line)]
    for word in (words):
        if word in sums:
            sums[word] += 1
        else:
            sums[word] = 1
print sums
fh.close
```

result shows

```
{'and': 1, 'heart': 1, 'love': 2, 'is': 1, 'pass': 1, 'rest': 1, 'wounded': 1, 'at': 3, 
'in': 3, 'lie': 1, 'winchelsea': 1, 'there': 1, 'easy': 1, 'you': 2, 'body': 1, 'be': 
1, 'rise': 1, 'shall': 4, 'may': 2, 'sussex': 1, 'montparnasse': 1, 'not': 3, 'knee': 
1, 'bury': 3, 'tongue': 1, 'champmedy': 1, 'i': 5, 'quiet': 1, 'air': 2, 'fresh': 1, 
'the': 1, 'grass': 1, 'my': 3}
```

The code print all the word and count frequency word use.

I would like to print dict in separate line.

```
'and': 1
'heart': 1
'love': 2
...
```

Any possible way to do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(sums)
{'air': 2,
 'and': 1,
 'at': 3,
 'be': 1,
 'body': 1,
 ....., # and so on...
 'you': 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>>for x in sums:
    print(repr(x),":",dic[x])


'and' : 1
'heart' : 1
'sussex' : 1
'rise' : 1
'love' : 2
'be' : 1
'may' : 2
'the' : 1
'is' : 1
'in' : 3
'body' : 1
'rest' : 1
'at' : 3
'pass' : 1
'not' : 3
'knee' : 1
'air' : 2
'bury' : 3
'tongue' : 1
'lie' : 1
'winchelsea' : 1
'i' : 5
'there' : 1
'grass' : 1
'quiet' : 1
'shall' : 4
'montparnasse' : 1
'fresh' : 1
'easy' : 1
'wounded' : 1
'you' : 2
'champmedy' : 1
'my' : 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `iteritems` to iterate through keys and values and thus be able to format the output as you want. Assuming strings as keys and ints as values:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print '%s: %d' % (k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another complex way using lambda

```
f = lambda *x: null; 
f( *( print( x,":",y ) for x,y in mydict.iteritems() ) )
```

Output

```
key2 : 2
key1 : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 - method name and syntactical updates - nice collection of swizzles

1 - lambdas are throw-away anonymous functions mainly used with filter, map, reduce etc.
Here were are creating a function containing a print and key,value iteration.

```
f = lambda *x: None; 
f( *( print( x,":",y ) for x,y in genre_counting.items() ) )

Games : 3862
Productivity : 178
Weather : 72
Shopping : 122
Reference : 64
Finance : 104
```

2 - repr() returns the canonical string representation of the object.

```
for x in genre_counting:
print(repr(x),":",genre_counting[x])

'Games' : 3862
'Productivity' : 178
'Weather' : 72
'Shopping' : 122
'Reference' : 64
'Finance' : 104
```

3 - %s is a string placeholder; %i is an integer placeholder

```
for k, v in genre_counting.items():
print( '%s : %i' % (k, v) )

Games : 3862
Productivity : 178
Weather : 72
Shopping : 122
Reference : 64
Finance : 104
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use any additional function, use simple for loop,

```py
student = {"Name":"Chandler Bing","Age":24,"Subject":["Sarcasm","Joke"]}
print(student)
for i in student:
    print(i,":",student[i])
```

```
Name : Chandler Bing
Age : 24
Subject : ['Sarcasm', 'Joke']
```