# Print each argument on different lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Snippet of code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some values.')

parser.add_argument('--proj', metavar='P', type=str, nargs= 1,
                    help='Identify the project')

parser.add_argument('--summ', metavar='S', type=str, nargs= '+',
                    help='Write a summary')

args = parser.parse_args()

a = vars(args)

print(a)
```

Execute `python3 filename.py`

Output:

```
{'proj': None, 'summ': None}
```

This is only a single line printed.

Instead I want to see:

```
{'proj' : None,

 'summ' : None}
```

This has multiple lines printed, thus easier to read output. Please clarify if any other detail needed.

Comment: That's nothing to do with argparse, that's just how Python represents a dictionary. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10279712/3001761

Comment: Yes I removed the label but that still doesn't help me determine how to get the output to print multiple lines instead of a single line.

Comment: Easier readability. Eventually I'll be adding in user input for each of these arguments along with a few other things.

Comment: ballpointBen, thanks, I am eventually passing into a json file but not sure the width solutions will work. I just tried that pprint method and got TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try pretty-printing it:

```
>>> args = {'prog': None, 'summ': None}
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(args)
{'prog': None,
'summ': None}
```

See this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279727/9717184).

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @WSLUser If you found my answer useful, please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry! I marked it appropriately